# JavaFX - handle MouseEntered event on a button (with fxml)

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, fxml

I'm trying to learn event handling and made an example with an fxml button that looked like that:

```
<Button fx:id="button" onAction="#Handle">
```

and the following handler method in my controller:

```
@FXML
 private void Handle () {

    btn_welcome.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {

        System.out.println("test");

    });
```

So far this works fine. Now I would like to handle the event of entering the button with the mouse. I tried

```
@FXML
 private void Handle () {

    btn_welcome.setOnMouseEntered((event) -> {

        System.out.println("test");

    });
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shoud not put another listener onto a control to get it to execute the function. What you are doing is adding another listener every single time you call your handle method.

Use `onMouseEntered="#methodToBeCalled"` in FXML, and in your code just create that method:

```
@FXML
public void methodToBeCalled(){
   System.out.println("mouse entered");
}
```

It's that simple. The method will be called, and all you have to do is specify id/method name, and use annotation.

Comment: I recommend you to download and use SceneBuilder, you gonna learn javafx faster, and be more productive.

Answer (score -1):

you can also try this

```
 btn_welcome.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED,
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
          @Override
          public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
           //your code here
          }
        });
```